# Focus back on textbox after submitting using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to introduce a dynamic search function in my project.  I have created a search form in my view which submits on `keyup` but the issue that I'm not facing is that when the view reloads, the text box is no longer in focus and so the user needs to click back onto it which obviously isn't ideal.

My view is set up as follows:

```
<form id="searchForm" asp-action="Index" method="get">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-9">
            <input type="text" id="fooSearch" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-outline-secondary form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <a asp-action="Index" asp-route-recent="true" class="btn btn-outline-secondary form-control">Recent</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

with the following JQuery script to submit on `keyup`

```
        $(function () {
            $('#fooSearch').keyup(function () {
                $('#searchForm').submit();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Can anyone help me to retain focus on the search textbox when the DOM is loaded?

Comment: did you try preventdefault?

Comment: before submit store document.active element in some fashion ( local storage etc) then on page load set the focus

Comment: Is the form submit asynchronous? Or is the page reloading?

Answer (score 0):

To give the focus back to the searchbar, you can use jQuery's `focus()`, e.g.:

```
$("#fooSearch").focus();
```

Now, where you place this depends on whether your form submit is synchronous (and makes the page reload) or asynchronous.

If the submit is asynchronous, then you can place this in your `keyup` event handler, right after the code that submits:

```
$('#fooSearch').keyup(function () {
    $('#searchForm').submit();
    $("#fooSearch").focus(); //focus back on the search bar
});
```

Otherwise, you will need to call `focus()` from an `onload` event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fooSearch").focus();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In all cases, first load or reload (submit), the focus should be on the search textbox so I think that you can just focus the textbox on load.

```
$(function() { $("#fooSearch").focus();});
```

The problem you may encouter is that the cursor will not be in the end of the keywords. So I think that the best option here is to use Ajax to the update the results each time the user change the keywords. Maybe waiting a few seconds before each update is a good idea also.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using html5 you can just add autofocus to your html tag something like:

```
<input type="text" id="fooSearch"  autofocus ="autofocus" name="searchString" value="@ViewData["currentFilter"]" class="form-control" />
```